# ios combine image view and UIlabel

Tags: ios, uiimageview, textview, uilabel

In android, a TextView has facilities to add accompanying images to a text. Basically instead of juxtaposing an ImageView and a TextView, I can use a TextView to add an image next to a text. Does something similar exist in iOS?

Comment: The best I've been able to do is load a UIWebView (transparent background in CSS and objective-c) with `<text area>` HTML code, and then use HTML `<IMG SRC>` to put my images inside my text fields with CSS `:in-line`

Comment: No, but it shouldn't be too complicated to code a custom `UIView` that layouts an `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a custom UIView like this

```
@interface ImageAndTextView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@end
```

You can drag and drop a UIView in storybaord and set the class to this class and connect the outlets.

You can also set up their location etc in storyboard or in the .m file.

Hth